# To bind or do not to bind

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

What's the difference between these code samples? Which approach is right?

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblShorName" runat="server" Text="<%#Customer.ShorName%>" />
 lblShorName.DataBind();
```

and

```
lblShorName.Text = Customer.ShorName;
```

Comment: First approach is better when you want to change even sites in production on runtime because it does not need to be compiled. Second is better because it's is precompiled, more readable and encapsulates the model from the view. Besides the latter is less error-prone because you see compiler errors instead runtime-errors.

Comment: @Tim - Not entirely true - you cannot update the first approach on production if you've deployed a precompiled versionof your app, which you really should in order to find compile-time (ASP.NET compile-time) errors.

Comment: @Jakub: I didn't want to go into details therefore it was only a comment. What i wanted to say is, i use first approach only in test environment where i want to see/change values fast. But that's my subjective opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't much of a difference that I know of (though I'll be interested in other people's answers to correct me if I'm wrong on that).  It's just a matter of coding style and preference.

Personally, I prefer the latter.  I feel that it's cleaner and separates the markup from the functionality which drives the markup.  But that's just me.

(I also tend to prefer not using data binding where I don't feel I need to.  But, again, it's a preference of how you want to use the tooling that's provided.  For example, in an ASP.NET MVC view I'm more likely to write a loop and output HTML within that loop than I am to use any kind of repeater or grid control and bind data to it.  Just personal preference.)

A lot of it also comes down to where in your application you want to perform these actions.  The former example keeps it on the page, whereas the latter example can be wrapped in conditionals, re-factored into another method, etc.  If it's possible that the value in question isn't *always* going to come from `Customer.ShortName` then I'd go with the latter example to add that additional logic around it.

Comment: Also, the second one will give you a compile-time errors, while the first one will blow up when you visit the page (or during ASP.NET precompilation) - ie. when you've renamed `Text` to `Description`.

Comment: @Jakub Konecki: Good point.  Though recently I've been torn between reliance on compile-time checking (_very_ useful in a continuous integration build) and dynamic languages (Ruby, JavaScript, etc.).  I've always taken compile-time checking for granted, but despite what proponents of dynamic languages may say I still think it's a very useful step, for precisely the example you give.

Answer (score 1):

The approach depends when you want to set the label. `lblShorName.Text = Customer.ShorName;` Can be used in different methods, events, timers. If you want to set it only at the beginning you can use the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Not much really, when you use databinding your value is set at the time of databinding, however if you set it in the code-behind you can set it any stage of the pages lifecycle.

You may have some logic behind the value too and this is more readable/maintainable in the code-behind.